# How can I promote NumPy on my website without breaking their license agreement?

Tags: numpy

My website uses NumPy to perform data operations, and I want to promote that fact. My website will eventually be used as a commercial product to generate income (for myself)— does this violate NumPy’s license agreement? If so, how can I obtain their permission? (I couldn’t find a way to contact the NumPy developers through the NumPy website.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NumPy license is avaliable at: [Numpy License](https://numpy.org/license.html)

And while

> Neither the name of the NumPy Developers nor the names of any contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

You may promote your use of NumPy as some sort factoid, you may not use NumPy to promote your product.

However, if you want to recommend NumPy to others, this would probably be greatly appreciated!

---

It would probably be OK to write:

> This website is powered by `NumPy`!

It would probably not be OK to write:

> This website is approved by the `NumPy` developers~